I'm asking about writing a Ghidra script - how is this not RE related?
So this question may seem too generic on first glance but I have tagged it with Ghidra - does tags not mean anything - in any case I added a [Ghidra] to clarify even more that I'm asking about Ghidra script.
I don't want this question to be lost because even myself I would like to have it as a future reference.
[Ghidra]How to set global variable type?

You are right, but your question really didn't do a lot to bring this aspect out (other than the tag). Thanks for bringing this up. PS: I am also guilty of not reading closer.
